# Button to input selection from DropDown into text area, text instantly disappears

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, apologies for the low level of Javascript I'm about to post. I just started playing around with it in my spare time last week to set something up to make my life at work easier.

In a nutshell, I work at a call centre. At the end of each call I have to enter notes into the system. I wanted to create a HTML page where I can simply click a few things and the notes will be ready for me to cut and paste. I'm now playing with drop down menus instead of a billion buttons.

I have a function that is triggered on a button press, which I'd like to then enter text into a textarea based on the selection from a drop down menu. For some reason (that I can't find an answer for), the text appears and then instantly disappears.

Here's my function:

```
function openCall() {
    var callerselection = document.fsnotes.caller.value;
    if (callerselection = "CH") {
        document.fsnotes.notesentry.value += "CH called ";
    }
}
```

Here's the Form:

```
<form name="fsnotes">
    <textarea rows="8" cols="50" name="notesentry"></textarea>
    </br>
    <select name="caller">
        <option>CH</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick="openCall()">OK</button>
</form>
```

Naturally I have a lot more in my main html file, I just have this smaller one to test new ideas in, as a lot of people in my department are now using the one with a billion buttons.

Comment: Change `callerselection = "CH"` to `callerselection == "CH"`

Comment: Thanks Mark, tried that, still seems to appear in the textarea and then instantly disappear. This is in Chrome, doesn't appear to do anything at all in IE or Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is submitting your form.

Change the button to:

```
<button onClick="openCall(); return false;">OK</button>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9m5k5amh/3/

Also see: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)